# Sacar diferencia entre dos DateTime en Knime

Tags: datetime

Necesito sacar la diferencia entre dos columnas con formato DateTime, me consta que se utiliza el nodo Date&Time Difference. Sin embargo el mensaje que me sale al configurar el nodo es el siguiente:[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué necesito cambiar para poder configurarlo? ¿El nombre de las columnas? En mi caso las columnas se llaman: approveddate y closeddate.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

[Me respondieron por Twitter](https://twitter.com/CadiliD/status/1521832851146219521?cxt=HHwWgoC5wci60Z4qAAAA):

> "Hola Álvaro, el nodo Date&Time Difference es el correcto pero tienes que transformar anteriormente las columnas en el formato Date&Time."

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Además, procura agregar más detalles a la misma.